# Redux withRouter in static method of superclass

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, typescript-generics

I have TodoContainer class, this extends Container class.

```
export interface IAttributeProps {
    site: string;
}

export interface IStateProps {}
export interface IDispatchProps {}
export type PropsTypes = IAttributeProps & IStateProps & IDispatchProps & RouteComponentProps;
export interface IReactStates {}
export type StateTypes = IReactStates;

class TodoContainer extends Container<PropsTypes, StateTypes> {
...
}
export default TodoContainer.connect<IStateProps, IDispatchProps, RouteComponentProps>();
```

At the end of above code, it connects static method `TodoContainer.connect` when TodoContainer module is imported. However, that `TodoContainer.connect` static method is actually in its parent class `Container`. So whenver above TodoContainer module is imported and used, it calls a static method in its parent class `Container`, as shown below:

```
class Container<P, S> extends React.Component<P, S> {
...
static connect<S, D, R extends RouteComponentProps>() {
        this.__connected = true;

        return withRouter(ReactRedux.connect<S, D, R>(
            (state) => {
                let mapper = this['mapper'];
                return mapper ? mapper(state) : {} as any;
            }
        )(this));
...
```

And I used them like follwing:

```
render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <TodoContainer site={"hello"} />
            </div>          
        );
    };
```

And I get following error on `site={"hello"}` above:

```
Type '{ site: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<Pick<unknown, never> & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>, never>, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.
  Property 'site' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<Pick<unknown, never> & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>, never>, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.ts(2322)
```

**In order to remove this error**, if I set `any` as return type of that static method in Container class, then it runs well without an error, like following:

```
static connect<S, D, R extends RouteComponentProps>() : any {
...
}
```

`OR EITHER WAY`, at the end of TodoContainer, if I cast the value returned by static method connect to `any` type, it also runs well without an error, like following:

```
export default TodoContainer.connect<IStateProps, IDispatchProps, RouteComponentProps>() as any;
```

**Once I set any type like above, then the another problem occurs.** If I remove site when to render TodoContainer, like following:

```
render() {
    
            return (
                <div>
                    <TodoContainer />
                </div>          
            );
        };
```

The problem is that it does not show an error or warning for not setting `site` props.

How can I fix this so that it will print an error for not having required props declared in interface IAttributeProps above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues with the conception of the generics you introduced. Though it might be none of my business, I took myself the freedom, to rename the generics in a more speaking manner in order to see potential issues.

From what I understood, is that the `Container` is used to generify the usage of `Redux`.

Inside the static function (of the `Container`) a reference to a `mapper` is made. This seems fragile, as there is no type-safety inside of it.

My suggestion is: *Overthink this pattern*

**NOTE:** This suggestion is based on my shallow understanding of your posted snippets.

TL;DR: The main issue was the `S` generic defined by `Container` and used by its static method.

This is what I came up with:

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router";

class Container<PropsForComponent extends RouteComponentProps, StateForComponent> extends React.Component<PropsForComponent, StateForComponent> {
    public static connectViaRedux<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps extends RouteComponentProps>() {
        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
            const mapper = Container["mapper"];
            return mapper ? mapper(state) : ({}) as any;
        };

        return withRouter(connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(mapStateToProps)(Container));
    }
}

interface TodoProps {
    site: string;
}
interface StateProps {}
interface DispatchProps {}

class TodoContainer extends Container<TodoProps & RouteComponentProps, {}> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <h1>{this.props.site}</h1>
        );
    }
}

const ConnectedTodoContainer = TodoContainer.connectViaRedux<StateProps, DispatchProps, TodoProps & RouteComponentProps>();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <ConnectedTodoContainer /> {/* <-- errors now correctly */}
            <ConnectedTodoContainer site="bla"/>
        </>
    );
};
```